# Нужна помощь с выводом матрицы

Tags: c++, математика

Написал функцию создания матрицы и подсчета её определителя, но не могу написать функцию вывода матрицы. Вместо всех строк и столбцов вывод только 1 столбец.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int arr(int j, int i, int num[3][3])
{
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << "mas[" << i << "][" << j << "]= ";
            cin >> num[i][j];
        }
    }
        return 0;
}

void GetMatr(int num[3][3], int i, int j)
{
    int ki, kj, di, dj;
    di = 0;
    for (ki = 0; ki < 3 - 1; ki++) 
    { 
        if (ki == i) di = 1;
        dj = 0;
        for (kj = 0; kj < 3 - 1; kj++) 
        { 
            if (kj == j) dj = 1;
            num[ki][kj] = num[ki + di][kj + dj];
        }
    }
}

int show (int num[3][3])
{
    int j, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << num[i][j] << " " << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

int det(int num[3][3])
{
    int df, ds, dr;
    df = (num[0][0] * num[1][1] * num[2][2]) + (num[1][0] * num[2][1] * num[0][2]) + (num[2][0] * num[0][1] * num[1][2]);
    ds = (num[1][2] * num[2][1] * num[2][0]) + (num[1][0] * num[2][2] * num[0][1]) + (num[2][1] * num[0][0] * num[1][2]);
    dr = df - ds;
    cout << "matrix determinant: " << dr << endl;
    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    int sw, j = 0, i = 0, m[3][3];
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "1 - creation a matrix, 2 - show the matrix, 3 - determinant\n";
        cin >> sw;
        switch(sw)
        {
        case 1:
            arr(j, i, m);
            break;
        case 2:
            show(m);
            break;
        case 3:
            det(m);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Repeat the attempt\n";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что ваша функция show выводит все числа по одному и делает перенос на новую строку. Прочитайте внимательно, что там написано. После первой же итерации по i у вас происходит выход из функции. Поменяйте логику вывода, так чтобы в цикле по j всё выводилось без переноса, а в цикле по i поставьте перенос строки.

Comment: ок, @Max. Но не могли бы вы подсказать, как это сделать?

Comment: @Max, Эксперимента ради я заменил int на void и поставил перенос строки на следующей строке. Как я теперь могу видеть - всё работает. Большое спасибо за совет!

void show (int num[3][3])
{
 int j, i;
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
   cout << num[i][j] << " ";
  cout << endl;
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

```
void show (int num[3][3])
{
    int j, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << num[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```